# How to make an .exe generated by Visual Studio 2013 run in other computers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Greetings to everyone in this forum.

I just finished my mid-term project in Visual Studio 2013 for collegue and my professor want us to give him the .exe of the project. The problem is that it only works in my computer. When I try to open the .exe in other computers, this error shows up:

- The program can't start because MSVCP120.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I was wondering if there is any way to fix this problem, so that the .exe can work in any computer that run Windows.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Install the Visual Studio runtime library.  This is well-documented.

Comment: That's because each visual studio version links by default with its own runtime library, you must make sure the target machine has redistributables for that version installed, for MSVC2013 for example: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Comment: Did you compile it in release mode?

Comment: So, is the solution just to install Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 0):

You are dynamically linking with the C++ runtime libraries meaning you need some extra dlls to go along with your exe. You can either install the VC++ redistributable package (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) or static link the libraries.

If you want to keep it down to a single executable I'd suggest the static linking route. In VS2013,

- right click on the project in the project explorer and select properties
- In the project tree open Common Properties, C/C++, Code Generation.
- Find the Runtime Library item in the right pane and change from Multi-threaded DLL to Multi-threaded.
- You can do similar for the debug configuration.

Comment: I can't find C/C++ and therefore, Code Generation.

Comment: It's on the project settings page on your project browser. However I think the distributable is the preferred route. Just look at most steam games, always installing the distributable whenever you download a new game and start it the first time.